# Can I set the styles of a specific date or range of dates in NSDatePicker

Tags: cocoa

My program uses a NSDatePicker but does not allow the user to choose any dates before the current date.

Is there a way to set all previous dates as visually grayed to indicate to them they cannot choose them?

Answer (score 0):

You can call setMinDate: on the NSDatePickerCell with [NSData date]

Comment: Yes to limit the selection but does this visually disable the dates out of range?